# How to convert image Xfile to URL in flutter?

Tags: flutter, url, uri, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

in my flutter App, I am using ana Image picker,
now I want to update the current user photoUrl(Firebase auth) but I don't know how to convert a file to Url?

Any idea??

`final XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);`

Comment: You can't just convert a file to a url. I faced the same problem in my app and just uploaded the image to Firebase Storage. From there, you can get the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebase Storage to upload an Image on Firebase and get ImageUrl

Use this dependency: **firebase_storage: ^11.0.10**

```
void uploadImage(String value) async {
if (await Utils.hasNetwork()) {
  Utils.showLoader();
  File image = File(value);
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref =
      storage.ref().child("${SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserId()}");
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
  uploadTask.then((res) {
    if (res.state == TaskState.success) {
      res.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
       print(url);
      }).catchError((onError) {
        print("Got Error $onError");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

}